# Can we change the [overflow] tag away from its original meaning of CSS?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

I'd like to start by saying that it's very difficult to find posts about the [overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overflow) tag, since it's a needle in the haystack of discussions about "Stack *Overflow*", so pardon me if this issue was already discussed in the past.

**The reason for my post is** that I was trying to tag a post about "floating-point number overflow" appropriately. When typing "overflow" I got the suggestions below:

[image]

I was faced with a choice between [integer-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integer-overflow) (which is only partly relevant as it deals with a different sort of numbers) or [overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overflow) whose excerpt, as of now, says:

> Overflow is a CSS property which governs what happens if content overflows its containing box.

One might notice that [css-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-overflow) is a synonym for [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), which indicates that the community didn't think it was necessary to have a separate tag for *overflow in the context of CSS*. I would argue that a post tagged as [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)+[overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overflow) would define the topic adequately.

I suggest making [overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overflow) more general, by removing its absolute focus on CSS and suggesting users to provide "additional tags" to better identify the context, as is done in many similar cases.

Comment: If it were a "more general" tag, couldn't the argument be made that it was actually a meta-tag?

Comment: A problem I can see with making [tag:overflow] more general is that *anything* can overflow. An integer, a CSS frame, a bathtub... Probably there has been some thought on using the tag solely for CSS-purposes (although I agree that [tag:css-overflow] would be more appropriate).

Comment: @Adriaan Luckily bathtubs are built with overflow drains, so at least **that** is mostly covered. We need to ask the bathtub builders how to implement the same kind of thing for software, though.

Comment: On [diy.se](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bathtub+overflow), [tag:bathtub] + [tag:overflow] is exactly what they do.

Comment: If we made overflow tag more general then it will be highly abused. People will use it to indicate errors. What will overflow tag under certain questions tell about the question which will be adequately enough to judge the question’s aim?

Comment: What I believe, collectively is that the key to make tags that are abused is to make the tags more _general_. Tags should be specific to the context and describe questions, they aren’t meant to be general, ignoring the exceptions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic-overflow

Comment: Consider going to https://stackoverflow.com/tags and entering "overflow". There you can see all of the tags that mention overflow.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, that does seem fitting! That tag requires some information though...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I meant Meta posts, not tags that contain this word.

Comment: I was talking about not finding an "overflow" tag which matched your use case. Going to the tags page allows for more tags to be displayed.

Answer (score 6):

Since there is already a synonym for [css-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-overflow), then *in theory* we should get rid of [overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overflow). It definitely meets the burnination criteria:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No, it is completely ambiguous.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Overflow could mean anything. Bathtub, mathematical, buffer, stack, this site etc etc.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No.

---

***However***, it is 4887 questions having this useless tag. Probably not worth the effort. I'd say let it be.

Comment: A tag being big is not really an obstacle to suggest burnination. We've burned bigger ---fish--- tags already. Especially with a bit of mod-magic to automatically deal with cases such as [tag:css]+[tag:overflow] this should go pretty fast.

Comment: I do think that this tag is ambiguous and should be cleaned up, if not fully burninated; and I also think as a [tag:css] gold badge holder that we don't need a [tag:overflow] tag for CSS questions in addition to just tagging them with [tag:css].

Comment: -1 Because of the last line. It will take up time to burninate but is that a reason for we should not at all disambugate the tag? If we let it will be then it will stay and used by people but it serves no purpose

Answer (score 5):

I want to add that the overflow tag has been, and it is used incorrectly to indicate integer-overflow or buffer-overflow, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boverflow%5D+is%3Aquestion+-html+-css+-%5Bhtml%5D+-%5Bcss%5D+-scroll).

I suggested several retags, that have been approved. Considering this, I propose to burninate it.