# Rename [overflow]

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

#### TLDR

The CSS-related tag [overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overflow) is being misused for other purposes. 40-ish% of the tagged questions are unrelated. -> A rename of the tag should be considered.

### Issue

An [overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overflow) of unrelated questions appears to be plaguing said tag. The tag is to be used for CSS, as per its excerpt:

> Overflow is a CSS property which governs what happens if content overflows its containing box. Do not use this tag for stack buffer overflow bugs and vulnerabilities; use [buffer-overflow] and/or [stack-smash] instead.

Of the over 6 100 questions, only about [3 600 contain the CSS tag as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css+overflow).

Excluding web-frameworks like [flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter), we get about [2 400 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overflow+-css+-flutter+-vue.js), most of which are unrelated to CSS.

#### Suggestion

The tag should be renamed.

Possible new names:

- [css-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-overflow) (currently a synonym for [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) apparently)
- [content-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/content-overflow)
- [element-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/element-overflow)

The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overflow/info) already refers to appropriate tags for the unrelated questions, should a cleanup be considered:

> Do not use this tag for questions about a stack overflow, buffer overflow or stack smashing error or vulnerability. See the appropriate tag(s) instead: [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow), [buffer-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buffer-overflow), [stack-smash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-smash).

Comment: Do we really need a tag for each css property?

Comment: @BDL No. Tags are (supposed to be) created as needed. Given there are over 3 000 legitimate questions, this seems to be the case.

Comment: Seeing as css-overflow is a synonym of css, that's probably a sign a rename isn't a good idea

Comment: Related: [Can we change the \[overflow\] tag away from its original meaning of CSS?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389320/6296561)

Comment: I like the comment discussion in that related thread. Bathtubs don't overflow because there is a guard against it designed into them. We should put holes in our software as well I guess!

Comment: Oh... bathtubs can overflow. I know this from experience.

Comment: @BDL No we do not.

Comment: @BDL We do not need a tag for every individual property (like `overflow-wrap`, `overflow-y`, `overflow-x`, `overflow`, `overflow-block`, …), but we do need a tag for every CSS *concept*.

Answer (score 28):

I don't think we need to rename the tag; I think we need to remove it... there's already plenty of disambiguated tags to choose from (see below). Besides that, most (all?) properties in CSS do not need their own tags... rarely is someone an *expert* in some single CSS property. More likely they're just knowledgeable of the module that contains/implements the property, or how the property interacts in a broader level with content/markup and other properties.

Most of the questions with this tag that are not tagged [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) are probably still about CSS... or they are about [buffer-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buffer-overflow) (the second one I looked at was tagged both [buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buffer) and [overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overflow) for example) or another type of arithmetical overflow.

I suggest we re-tag (yes, what fun...) questions with [overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overflow) as follows:

- If they're about CSS (even via some abstraction like React, or JS in general), use [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) instead
- If they're about buffer overflows, use [buffer-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buffer-overflow)

  - Replace [buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buffer)+[overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overflow) with just [buffer-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buffer-overflow) where appropriate
- If they're about integer overflows, use [integer-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integer-overflow) instead
- If they're about stack overflows, use [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow) instead

I'm not sure if there is another type of overflow that needs to be considered, but if so it can be added to this list.

Comment: "*rarely is someone an expert in some single CSS property. More likely they're just knowledgeable of the module*" - agreed, but certainly the [[tag:css-overflow]] tag refers to **the [overflow module](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-overflow)** as a whole not to the `overflow` property alone. And we should have a tag for this concept, instead of tagging all CSS questions only [[tag:css]].

Comment: _I'm not sure if there is another type of overflow that needs to be considered, but if so it can be added to this list_  -- there's Overflow Flag in assembly, at least in x86, possibly in others, it is closely related with [tag:integer-overflow] though

Comment: @Bergi That module is still in WD stages after all these years with numerous issues and 'todos' still listed in the latest published draft; many of the properties it discusses are new or experimental and have not been implemented by any vendor. Perhaps it would be worth a moderator de-synonymizing [tag:css-overflow] from [tag:css], but I'm not sure it's at that point yet. I don't proclaim to be an expert in everything that module currently covers, though--I am just familiar with the non-experimental parts of it, like overflow and text-overflow.

Comment: @Bergi I also think we do _not_ need a tag for every single CSS module. There are hundreds of them... and at that point we wouldn't need the [tag:css] tag anymore.

Comment: Given we have currently 782,933 CSS questions, I don't think a hundred tags for the individual topics would do any harm.

Comment: @Bergi The problem is that not all modules are as eponymous as, say, flexbox or grid. If someone has issues with padding or margins, askers (and probably most potential answerers) aren't going to know that those are part of the box model module, so trying to enforce usage of that tag is going to be a Sisyphean task. That kind of change is going to be a net increase (forever) in the amount of work needed to maintain questions and in the difficulty of using appropriate tags, which is the _opposite_ of the goal here.

Comment: @TylerH One could create [css-margin] and [css-padding] as synonyms for [css-box-model] in cases like that. But still, I'd rather have too many different too small/specific tags, that we can later synonymise, than not have any tags at all. There is no harm in adding extra tags, as long as they do not prevent other more useful tags from being applied to a question.